# Bundle c++ application using libc.so.6

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, libc, dynamic-library

I'm Trying to make my executable portable on linux, to do this i need to copy all the shared library used by the program itself, to check which one do I need I use:

```
ldd program_name
```

The output of the program helps me find all the required `.so`, between these libraries there is:

```
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5b61ac2000)
```

At this point I copied all the libraries in a folder called `shared_libs` and shipped them alongside the program to another pc, the problem arise when i do:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./shared_libs ./program_name
```

which gives:

```
[1]    4619 segmentation fault (core dumped)  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./shared_libs ./program_name
```

I'm pretty sure that libc.so.6 is causing the problem because if I do:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./shared_libs ls
```

with just that library in the shared_libs folder, `ls` gives seg fault as well.

How can i bundle my application?

**EDIT 1: Why i don't link statically everything?**

I tried it, The only thing i got was headache...

Comment: Why don't you link all the libraries statically?

Comment: Use the debugger.

Comment: Neither linking with glibc statically nor copying parts of glibc over to the target platform are working solutions to the portability problem. Don't do that. Link dynamically, don't copy parts of glibc (you can copy other libraries), and solve any problems that arise on the case-by-case basis.

Comment: @S.M. On ls? Or perhaps on ld.so?

Comment: @n.m. i can't solve problem coming from every pc the program is shipped to

Comment: You can announce that you only support PCs that have at least some minimal glibc version (and link against that version). Or link statically against an alternative libc implementation with no portability issues like [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/intro.html).

Comment: The main issues were caused by libc.so and libdl.so, i guess i can safely suppose that every system has a decent version for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to do this i need to copy all the shared library used by the program itself

No, you *don't*. In particular, copying GLIBC simply doesn't work (as you've discovered).

What you *actually* need is to build your program against an old enough (not newer than any of systems you distribute your program to) libc, and then depend on GLIBC ABI compatibility (which guarantees that programs linked against old GLIBC continue to run correctly when bound to newer GLIBC at runtime).

This can be achieved by either building your program on an old system, or using a `chroot`, or building a "linux to older linux" cross-compiler.

> I'm pretty sure that libc.so.6 is causing the problem

Correct. The reason this doesn't work is explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

The problem is that GLIBC is composed of multiple binaries which all must match. And the path to one of these binaries (the `ld-linux`) is hard-coded into the program at static link time and can not be changed.